# Python duplicates data from JSON response

Tags: python, json

When I open python shell and run my code below it gives exactly 250 entries. But when I run it in the shell it gives me 500.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/pricinghistory/DPG/1Y'
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
price_data =  json_data['Data']

for i in price_data['PriceHistory']:
    print (i['Data'])
```

This is a sample from the json that I'm traing to manipulate:

```
{"Data":
    {"Period":"1Y",
    "PriceHistory":
        [{"NAVData":19.31000,
          "DiscountData":-14.19,
          "Data":16.57000,
          "DataDate":"2017-02-14T00:00:00",
          "DataDateJs":"2017/02/14",
          "DataDateDisplay":"2/14/2017"},           
         {"NAVData":19.33000,
          "DiscountData":-14.49,
          "Data":16.53000,
          "DataDate":"2017-02-15T00:00:00",
          "DataDateJs":"2017/02/15",
          "DataDateDisplay":"2/15/2017"},      
         {"NAVData":19.26000,
          "DiscountData":-14.38,
          "Data":16.49000,
          "DataDate":"2017-02-16T00:00:00",
          "DataDateJs":"2017/02/16",
          "DataDateDisplay":"2/16/2017"},
         {"NAVData":19.18000,
          "DiscountData":-14.18,
          "Data":16.46000,
          "DataDate":"2017-02-17T00:00:00",
          "DataDateJs":"2017/02/17",
          "DataDateDisplay":"2/17/2017"},
         {"NAVData":19.31000,"DiscountData":-
```

Somehow it duplicates the loop entries.

Comment: How are you running it from the shell? When I run this I find 251 entries in the `json_data['Data']['PriceHistory']` list.

Comment: I'm using Mandjaro linux, in the second shell comment I ment linux shell.
I can suply a screen shot if neaded.
When i run it with : python def.py | cat -n gives 502 entries.

Comment: What is the command you run to execute the program?

Comment: python def.py , Even in the Wing IDE is showing 502 lines.

Comment: Screen shots are strongly discouraged here. Instead, boil the problem down to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem reproducibly, ideally without fetching anything from the network.

Comment: I found what was with it, i thouth that I rename it to def.py , but not it was still json.py so the Linux shell and the Wing IDE ware right. I should re think my nameing conventions :). And never call a file with the lib name that I use.